# Ellipsize doesn't work any more - Android

Tags: android, textview

I have a `TextView` and I used to display correctly the three dots at the end of the text. Today I imported a library and changed `TextView` to a custom `TextView`. When I cleared all the changes and returned to my initial `TextView` code, for some reason the `ellipsize` doesn't work anymore.

I tried cleaning the project and rebuild but the problem remains. What am I doing wrong?

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/customtextview_description"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:ellipsize="end"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal|left"
     android:maxLines="3"
     android:padding="15dp" 
     android:textSize="15dp" />
```

When I use singleLine="true", only then I get the 3 dots at the end, but I need to have 3 lines.

Comment: set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.

Comment: set `android:maxLines="1"`

Comment: But I need maxLines=3 not 1

Comment: every thing looks ok , can you add a screen shot and complete xml file

Answer (score 0):

`elipsize` is work when you have text that is longer then your `TextView`'s width.
your code is right but if you use `maxLines 3` 
try Following which work.

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/customtextview_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:text="AAAAAAAAAAA\n aaaaaaa\n  SSSSSSSSSSssssssssssssssssssss ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|left"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/tile_height"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/tile_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/title_bottom_padding"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Error:error: attribute 'com.myapp.android.test:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf' not found.

Comment: You need to add this dependency in your build.gradle file:
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When I use

```
customtextview_description.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

the functionality of the `elipsize` stops.